# Member function template selection and SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I've been trying to understand the way C++ selects templates. Namely, consider the following code sample:

```cpp
template <typename R>
class Curious
{
public:
    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type = 33>
    void test1() {}

    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type = 33>
    void test1() {}

    template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value>::type>
    void test2() {}

    template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<T>::value>::type>
    void test2() {}

    template <typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<R>::value>::type * = nullptr>
    void test3() {}

    template <typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<R>::value>::type * = nullptr>
    void test3() {}

    // works
    template <typename T = void>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<R>::value, T>::type test4() {}

    template <typename T = void>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<R>::value, T>::type test4() {}

    // also works
    template <typename T = void, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<R>::value, T>::type * = nullptr>
    void test5() {}

    template <typename T = void, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<R>::value, T>::type * = nullptr>
    void test5() {}
}; // Curious
```

The first two functions (test1) work fine (**why?**):

```
Curious<int> curious;
curious.test1<int>();
curious.test1<const int>();
```

While the rest of them cause compilation errors. 
Regarding the function test2 the compiler claims I'm trying to create a duplicate:

```
error C2535: 'void Curious::test2(void)': member function already defined or declared
```

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) the documentation says:

> A common mistake is to declare two function templates that differ only
>   in their default template arguments. This is illegal because default
>   template arguments are not part of function template's signature, and
>   declaring two different function templates with the same signature is
>   illegal.

So it seems to be the case. However, I don't see that much difference from the first two functions, which also have the default template argument. Thus we have a default type (test2 - doesn't work) against a default value (test1 - works). Is there any rule about it?

In case of test3:

```
error C2039: 'type': is not a member of 'std::enable_if'
```

Like in the first case this time the member function template has a default non-type parameter, but it depends on the class template parameter. Now SFINAE doesn't skip the wrong one (also not sure why).

In the fourth case SFINAE resolves the template by the return type. But don't these test4 functions have identical signature? As they differ only in the return type.

As far as I understand, in the fifth case adding extra parameter makes test5 signature dependent on the function template parameter, therefore SFINAE kicks in and resolution works.

I'm quite confused about how C++ deals with these templates. Could somebody be so kind to clear these things up?

Comment: As a note, since C++14, you may replace `typename std::enable_if<cond>::type` by `std::enable_if_t<cond>`.

Comment: anyone would use if constexpr here?
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- With default value removed, for test1, you have:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type>
  void test1();

  template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type>
  void test1();
  ```

  Which have clearly different signatures.
- For test2:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename> void test2();

  template <typename T, typename> void test2();
  ```

  Which are clearly identical signatures.
- For test3, SFINAE doesn't apply as you have hard error as `R` is fixed in the class and your `enable_if` doesn't depend of template parameter of the function.
- For test4, there is an exception about signature for template function as overload may differ only by return type so

  ```
  int foo();
  char foo(); // Illegal.
  ```

  but

  ```
  template <typename T> int foo();
  template <typename T> char foo(); // legal, even it is not trivial to call
  ```

  In addition, `std::enable_if<!std::is_const<R>::value, T>::type` depends on template parameter `T` so it is ok.
- For test5, second template parameter depends on first template parameter `T`, so it is ok too.

Comment: Thank you, I've just added two more examples to my original post

Comment: Added explanation for test4/test5: `enable_if` does depend of `T` in both cases.